# Can I use my Endurance bike for my first race?

Tags: road-bike, racing, geometry, road

I recently got into road cycling, my first and only bike purchase has been a Scott endurance bike. Now that I am getting more and more comfortable on a road bike, a couple of guys I group ride with, are encouraging me to try road racing. I have been to a couple "Intro to crit racing clinics" and am thinking of entering my first CAT 5 race. My question is when beginning to road race, is an endurance bike ok to use? or should I consider purchasing a race bike?

Comment: Should be fine - just as long as you stay upright for the whole course then you'll have achieved something.  Doesn't matter what position you come in, as long as you're not a DNF.  Then again a DNF is better than a DidNotStart !

Comment: Also, make sure you get some large fast group riding in before you start. Totally different to riding on your own or with a couple of others.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an endurance bike will be fine.

I think most people outside Scott's marketing department would be hard pressed to name the differences.

The main differences are likely to be a longer wheelbase, slower steering, and a more upright riding position. Maybe slightly larger tires, but you can change those to whatever you feel you need.